# Force browser to download files using http/1.1 instead of http/2

Tags: javascript, angular, http2, http-1.1

Our network bandwidth is slow. So, when we trigger multiple downloads at once by "Download all" button on our website, after some time (not the same time always) all the downloads fail with "Failed: Network Error" regardless of the browser. Individual downloads work fine.

We noticed that the downloads are happening with http/2 instead of http/1.1 where the browser used to queue the downloads. So, if we had triggered 10 downloads parallelly, the browser used to download 5-6 at a time and only after one of them finished, the remaining ones would start. But with http/2 all the 10 downloads happen parallelly and all fail with "Failed: Network Error"

How can I fix this ? Can I force chrome/firefox/... to use http/1.1? Is there anything I can do on Java Script side to force http/1.1?

Comment: I think you can only control this serverside..?

Comment: What does the "Download all" button on the web site actually do? Perhaps some code for it if it's applicable?

Comment: your hosting has very limited bandwidth or it has high traffic? buy storage hosting, separate your website and download resources

Comment: @uingtea Our hosting has very limited bandwidth.